# Average doesn't calculate correctly in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

It wont be possible to share my data.

I've a lot of purchasing information with purchasing day, supplier, delivery value and quantity.
When I try to summarize it to get an average price per unit (Value / quantity), my calculations goes crazy.

Sometime delivered quantity for all deliveries haven't been registered, that results in "NaN". So i've been using a powerQuery to avoid that.
Formula: `= if [Delivered Quantity] = 0 then 0 else [Delivered Value]/[Delivered Quantity]`
Below is a picture of my problem, as you can see the "price per unit" is WAY to big.

[image]

[image]

Even if I delete the above formula and only use `[Delivered Value]/[Delivered Quantity]` and hide inifinity/NaN in filter, it still get some errors.

[image]

Comment: Weird, tried using an DAX formula: avg  price = sum('Sum Tbl'[Delivered Value]) / sum('Sum Tbl'[Delivered Quantity]) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

tried using an DAX formula:

```
avg price = 
     sum('Sum Tbl'[Delivered Value]) / sum('Sum Tbl'[Delivered Quantity])
```

and it worked.

Comment: if you change to  `SUMX('Sum Tbl','Sum Tbl'[Delivered Value]) / 'Sum Tbl'[Delivered Quantity])` it will be double faster

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that! 

I had to: 
Avg. Price = sumx('Sum Tbl', 'Sum Tbl'[Delivered Value]) / sumx('Sum Tbl', 'Sum Tbl'[Delivered Quantity])

Comment: No, only 1 SUMX() as I wrote. You can go with 2 SUM, it is also correct, but you double calculations with that.

Comment: `SUMX('Sum Tbl','Sum Tbl'[Delivered Value] / 'Sum Tbl'[Delivered Quantity])`

Comment: Tried the latest formula, it went haywire :( For example 942677 $ / 228 (deliveries) = 545000 $ avg price.

Comment: Hi @Fratia. Your are right formulas calculates in a different way. Your formula takes all values filtered by rows in the matrix and divides by all quantities. For example, you have `Val-qty: 100$-1pcs; 100$-9pcs`, you formula will return  `(100+100)/(1+9)=20`. My formula calculates like that: `100/1 + 100/9= 111,1`. To get a correct value with my formula a SUMX should be replaced by AVERAGEX. Thank you for your feedback, and sorry for a caused mess. Not SUMX, but AVERAGEX will work double faster, because it's goes through the table only once while `sum/sum` goes twice.

Comment: `AVERAGE([Delivered Value]/Delivered Quantity])`

Comment: Still not sure what is happening, tried this formula: `Avg. Price = AVERAGEX('Sum Tbl','Sum Tbl'[Delivered Value]/'Sum Tbl'[Delivered Quantity])`, got crazy numbers again. And it didn't work with: `Avg. Price = AVERAGE([Delivered Value]/Delivered Quantity])`

Comment: it can be because I missed "[" in the expression. I added now, please try `AVERAGE([Delivered Value]/[Delivered Quantity])`

Comment: Just get "Average function only accepts a column reference as an argument"

Comment: Just checked the syntax, only AVERAGEX will work like that `AVERAGEX('Sum Tbl','Sum Tbl'[Delivered Value]/'Sum Tbl'[Delivered Quantity])`

Comment: Little bit surprised that AVERAGE takes only a column ). Sorry for mess.

Comment: This also will work `AVERAGEX('Sum Tbl',DIVIDE('Sum Tbl'[Delivered Value],'Sum Tbl'[Delivered Quantity]))` The plus of the `DIVIDE()` it will return `BLANK()` if you'll try to divide by 0 and `AVERAGEX()` will skip the value, while direct dividing will return an error.